# How to skip unavailable drive letters

Tags: vb.net

I'm programming an application that must save a .txt file in user PC. I am currently using this code:

```
    Dim filepath As String = "G:\Username.txt"
    If Not System.IO.File.Exists(filepath) Then
        System.IO.File.Create(filepath)
    End If
```

And used this code for other local drives as `F:\` and `E:\` and `D:\`. Like this example

```
Dim filepath2 As String = "D:\Username.txt"
If Not System.IO.File.Exists(filepath2) Then
    System.IO.File.Create(filepath2)
End If

Dim filepath4 As String = "F:\Username.txt"
If Not System.IO.File.Exists(filepath4) Then
   System.IO.File.Create(filepath4)
End If
```

This code is working, however I am facing a problem If user PC just has 2 local drives except drive `C:\` such as `G:\` and `D:\`. When the code that attempts to save the .txt file to drive `F:\` the code fails to execute with a `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException`. I am looking to somehow skip the code if the drive is not available and to only execute the code when that local drive (e.g. `F:\`) is available.

Comment: Have you seen the [`DriveInfo.GetDrives()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method?

Comment: Note: Your current code does *not* work as expected. The `Create` method doesn't only create a file, it leaves it open and returns a `FileStream` object that you can use to write to it. As you ignore the returned object the code will leave the file open until the garbage collector removes the object and closes the file.

Comment: Thanks but I need a simple code to skip it can you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments to your question, your code may be creating a file on the specified drives, however it is leaving a handle open on the files. When the  Garbage Collection is comes along, the open handles on the files are removed. however if you were to try and modify those files while the application has them open you'll find that the file is locked. The method you are using, `IO.File.Create` returns a `FileStream` object. This object supports IDisposable and as such you should either be cleaning up after yourself, or implementing the `Using` directive.

Secondly, as the other answer has pointed out, your logic for checking if the file exists is flawed in that you'll get a false positive if the drive itself doesn't exist, not just the file. On a different thought path, using `File.Exists()` is almost never useful as it will never give you accurate results in real-time during run-time. There is always a possibility that the file's existence may change from the time that `File.Exists()` is called to when your application attempts to access the file; commonly known as a race condition. Instead you should be attempting to do whatever it is you are doing and then handling any type of exceptions that are occurring.

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Imports System.IO

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim fleName As String = "Username.txt"
        For Each drvInfo As DriveInfo In DriveInfo.GetDrives
            If drvInfo.DriveType = DriveType.Fixed AndAlso drvInfo.Name <> "C:\" Then
                Try
                    Dim fleStream As FileStream = File.Open(drvInfo.Name & fleName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
                    ' Do some stuff here
                    fleStream.Close()
                    fleStream.Dispose()

                    ' Or implement the 'Using' directive

                    Using fleStream As FileStream = File.Open(drvInfo.Name & fleName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
                        'do some stuff here
                    End Using
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                End Try
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm on windows form and your code isn't working on .. Can you explain how to use or just a simple code that works on windows form

Comment: @AmirJobs in a console application, the `Main()` sub is called when the program is run. The code I provided isn't going to be exactly copy/paste droppable into your winforms application. I suggest creating a test console application and then copy/paste the above code into the default `Module1` file and then use breakpoints to figure out how the code works. Once you understand what the code is doing you can implement what you need into your own project where you need it.

Comment: @AmirJobs - The code I provided will do exactly what you described in your question, but here on SO, we're not a "Help, do my work for me" community, so not all answers are direct solutions.

Answer (score 0):

From this:

```
If Not System.IO.File.Exists(filepath2) Then
```

It looks like you're saying (pseudo-code):

```
IF 'path including drive' does NOT exist, THEN create file
```

If you read that carefully, thinking it through, you'll notice:

If a drive doesn't exist, it will be classed as that path not existing. Therefore, it will attempt to create a file there and obviously fail.